# Minidlna doesn't see my second hhd

Tags: minidlna

I have a SSD that is not very large in capacity. I've added a hdd in my computer. With minidlna, I can see fine the files in my download folders, but when I try to see the files from my hdd, (the one I added beside my SSD) I just can't... Include a picture of what I tried to write in minidlna. Any tips on how I could see my files on my larger hdd? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably be file permissions, the minidlna server runs with the user:group minidlna:minidlna so if the files you have created are not either in a matching group, or are world readable then this process will not be able to scan or read them. You need execute permission on the directory to be able to list the files, and read permission on the files.
Show the permissions with `stat <filename>` and change the permissions with the `chmod` command.
To add the world readable to a file `chmod a+r <filename>`

Comment: I'll give it a try later on and let you know how it went! Thank you very much, your help is much appreciated!

Comment: I tried changing permissions to my directory, with chmod 755... it seemed to work, (I check with the "ll" command) but I still couldn't access my minidlna server set on my second hdd. It seems that everything that starts with /media/ has a problem with minidlna... I've searched a bit on the Internet and could'nt find anyting that worked. Now, I am new to Ubuntu, that might have something to do with it... anyway, thanks for your help. If you think of anything, please let me know!

Comment: I assure you that your problem is probably permissions. Also have a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266033/permissions-for-video-folder-for-minidlna?rq=1)

Comment: Yes, I came across that answer in my initial search. I did have a second look and it seemed that I overlooked something. I followed the steps of the best answer and... bingo, it worked! Now, it says that if I restart my computer, I might need to restart minidlna in order for it to work. I am not sure about that, I haven't restarted it yet. Thanks Stuart, your answer allowed me to learn a little more!